# size of UIImage stored as NSData?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsdata

Am i able to get the size (CGSize) of a UIImage stored as NSData without using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:];`? Being able to do this would make my code run faster.

Answer (score 2):

You won't with CoreGraphics or UIKit.  You'll need to inspect the binary stream.  Fortunately it's been done before in many other languages.  A quick google found [this implementation](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage/blob/master/lib/fastimage.rb) in Ruby that  determines file type (jpg, bmp, png and gif) and pulls the dimensions of the image.  Should be easy enough to convert to Objective-C using NSData.  Start from the [`parse_size`](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage/blob/master/lib/fastimage.rb#L243) function.

Answer (score 1):

An image stored as NSData can be in any number of formats such a png, jpg, tiff, gif, raw, etc. It's not a UIImage when all you have is a blob of bytes. So in general, you can't determine the size of an image stored as an NSData object.

If you can guarantee that every one of your NSData images are stored in the same format, say PNG, then you could scan the NData for the size information based on the PNG data file format. That may be more efficient than creating a UIImage from the data. But obviously that is a lot more work.

Comment: PNG is particularly easy to write a quick parser for to pull out the size information, if you have all PNGs. It's at the start of the IHDR chunk, which is the first chunk in the file: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

Comment: @Andrew: Looks like it's just as simple for JPG: http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html

Answer (score 0):

Write the size information it to some sort of DB when saving.

To get the size of the file on disk, you can use [`NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath%3aerror%3a)

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful [CGImageSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html) APIs. Ole Begemann has a great [tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/) on the topic.